# Symfony 2 related entities in 1 form

Tags: forms, symfony, entities

I have 2 entities, `topic` and `post`. `topic` contains the name of the topic. `post` contains the text and the topic id.
I want to implement a function into my project that allows users to create a new topic and write a post for their topic.

The form should look like this:

1. Name of the topic [input type=text] (property of topic entity)
2. text [textarea] (property of post entity)

Now I need help building the form. Only using the TopicType gives me the result I want, just without the input field to write a post. I tried adding

```
$builder->add('post', 'entity', array('class' => 'MyTestBundle:Post', 'property' => 'text'));
```

to my PostType but that creates a dropdown menu of the previous posts.

How can I create a form that contains all the input fields of 2 related entites?

Edit:

`Topic.orm.yml`

```
My\TestBundle\Entity\Topic:
type: entity
table: topics
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }


oneToMany:
    posts:
        targetEntity: Post
        mappedBy: topic

fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 50
```

`Post.orm.yml`

```
My\TestBundle\Entity\Post:
type: entity
table: posts
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }

manyToOne:
    topic:
        targetEntity: Topic
        inversedBy: posts
        joinColumn:
            name: topic_id
            referencedColumnName: id


fields:
    text:
         type: text
    datetime:
         type: datetime
```

Rendering the form worked with `$builder->add('posts', new PostType());` but when I submit the form i get this error:

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in C:\projects\symtests\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1375
```

How exactly do I have to handle the form and persist the submitted data to my database?

Unfortunately I deleted the code that should persist the data to the database, but it looked something like this, and it returns the same error.

```
public function persistAction()
{
    $topic= new Topic();
    $post = new Post();

    $topic->setCreateDate(new \Datetime('now'));
    // set all properties for $topic that you can't set in the form

    $post->setTopic($thread);
    $post->setDatetime(new \Datetime('now'));
    // set all properties for $psot that you can't set in the form

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ThreadType(), $thread);
    $form->bind($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $em->persist($topic);
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('success');
    }
    else
    {
        throw new \Exception('form invalid');
    }
```

Maybe I should try this: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: To handle forms, I can't do much more than prescribe the [Symfony2 doc about forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) Because your code works. How do you currently do this in your Controller ? Don't hesistate showing us more code so we can help you more

Comment: I added the code that should persist the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **TopicType.php** :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('posts', new PostType())
    ;
}
```

**EDIT1** : *text* is supposed to be the name of the attribute in your `Topic` class which links to your `Post` class.

In **PostType.php** :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('text', 'textarea')        
    ;
}
```

**EDIT2** : changed `text`  to `posts` in `TopicType.php` as you gave your mapping files ;)

Comment: With this solution I get
`Neither property "text" nor method "getText()" nor method "isText()" exists in class "My\TestBundle\Entity\Topic"`

Comment: "text" is supposed to be the name of the attribute used in "Topic" to link "Post" as it is a OneToOne relationship. If your attribute is called "post" then use this attribute name instead of "text" in my example. I don't know how your classes look like. You could edit your post and show us ;)

Comment: I added my mapping files.